# How to insert a few records?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I just installed MySQL version 5.5.8 and Workbench on my PC. I did a few simple kinds of things like creating a Schema and a Table or two. My question is this: Is there a WYSIWYG way of inserting a few records into one of my tables? When I look at the youtube videos the screens that I see there do not exactly match my Workbench screens. When I right click on a table I do not see anything that would allow me to add a few records. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy, provided your table is editable at all (that is, it has a primary key). Just run a normal select query like `select * from sakila.actor;` in the SQL IDE (which is shown when you have opened a connection).

This will open a result grid with the data from that table below the query editor. Beneath the result grid there should be two buttons (apply and cancel, revert on OS X) if the result set is editable. Now you can start changing values in any of the cells (depends a bit on the platform how to start editing, e.g. on Windows press `F2`, on Mac just press `<Enter>` after you selected a cell).

[image: Editing values of a table in MySQL Workbench 6.0 (OS X)]